# how to install compatible version of cudnn for tensorflow using conda

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I trying to ran a python code on gpu using tensorflow-gpu=1.6.0
I have installed tensorflow using conda command that suppose to install all the required lib
when I run the code I get the error below:

> Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7605 (compatibility version 7600) but source was compiled with 7102 (compatibility version 7100).  If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime matches a compatible version specified during compile configuration.
> 2021-02-16 02:29:34.892462: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)

anybody could help me how to find and install the compatible version using conda in order to solve this issue...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This page lists tensorflow/cudnn compatibility:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux

seems you will need to install cudnn 7 rather than 7.6 to use tf 1.6.0

Comment: dear @anax32 I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu=1.6 cudatoolkit=9.0 cudnn=7.0 using conda but I get "Package cudatoolkit conflicts for:
cudnn=7.0 -> cudatoolkit=8.0
tensorflow-gpu=1.6 -> tensorflow-gpu-base==1.6.0 -> cudatoolkit[version='8.0.*|9.0.*']
" and i have tried to search for a compatible version on anaconda.org but nothing exist i need a way to install them I even tried to use pip unfortunately nothing worked